# UIPageControl shifted the image over it (instead of being on top of it)

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Unfortunately this happens often but not always. We are developing an application that displays image/video in a powerpoint-ish way. At the bottom of the screen we have a UIPageViewControl that shows the current page in the UIPageViewController.

What happens is that when we present a UIView over the UIPageViewController and dismiss it, when the contents of the UIPageViewController is displayed it is shifted up of the size of the UIPageControl. When we touch the screen, the content is redrawn correctly under the UIPageController.

** Note that this happens only in iOS 7. In iOS 8 it works as expected. When xcode 6 and iOS 8 SDK weren't available, we did have that problem.

The following image is what we expect to see when we dismiss the presented UIView:
[image]

The following is what happens after dismissing the view
[image]

You can see that the UIPageControl is now opaque and that the image is shifted up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following setting was missing on my custom UIViewController:

```
viewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```